# Invalid conversion from runtime type Database.Error to Database.DuplicateError

Tags: apex

I am trying to convert Database.Error to Database.DuplicateError and to Datacloud.DuplicateResult. Below is the code snippet (no compile time error) -

```
Datacloud.DuplicateResult dupError = (Datacloud.DuplicateResult)(((Database.DuplicateError)((Database.Error)saveRes.getErrors()[0])).getDuplicateResult());
```

Now I am getting below error on DML

> Invalid conversion from runtime type Database.Error to Database.DuplicateError.

I am trying to do direct type conversion over here [referring this code snippet by Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Database_DuplicateError.htm#apex_class_Database_DuplicateError). Is there anything which we can do over here or I have to follow the way the link is saying?

Comment: Do you have a testing snippet you're using to throw these errors? Anything a user could run in execute anon? Could be helpful

Comment: @battery.cord - I don't have any code to help you with. I have a suggestion about how you can replicate this. Try Insert/update any record in APEX with Database.insert/update. Intentionally provide the exception in this DML  and in saveResult methods (!saveResult.isSuccess()) put this line of code you will get the exception. Please try this.

Comment: So, more or less the code used to generate the sample in the documentation? Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @battery.cord - I am unable to provide the code 2 reasons -

Answer (score 3):

I'm unable to repo this on my org (cs14, version 43). At first I thought it was due to something in your one-liner, since I used a expanded version (shown below), but that also worked fine.

I'd say its due to a `DmlException` being thrown, when your code expects a `DuplicateError`. Adding a hard failure (`insert new Account();`) to my account trigger causes the same error message, when using your one-liner:

> System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Database.Error to Database.DuplicateError

Personally, I think this is a fault on the authors of the documentation, since they try to cast a type without checking if its a member of that type. This is what `instanceof` is for. Adding a type-check before we do any casting to help handle different errors being mixed together should negate this problem entirely.

The line needed is `someError instanceof Database.DuplicateError`. The full code below was what I used to test.

```
String rawAccountJson = ''; // JSON Of an existing account used to create a duplicate of that account
// Use whatever values to trigger your rules 

// Create a dupe from our dupe json 
Account dupe = (Account)JSON.deserialize(rawAccountJson, Account.class);

Database.SaveResult result = Database.insert(dupe, false); // set false to avoid directly throwing an exception 

// One-Liner to ensure behavior is the same .. 
Datacloud.DuplicateResult dupError = (Datacloud.DuplicateResult)(((Database.DuplicateError)((Database.Error)result.getErrors()[0])).getDuplicateResult());

System.debug(dupError); // outputs raw exception data

// Should check each step of one-liner, instead of assuming theres n errors and that error[0] is of a type 

// Check sucess ...  
if (!result.isSuccess()) {

    // Insertion failed due to error 
    for(Database.Error duplicateError : result.getErrors()) {
        // !! Verify that record is a dupe before casting (via instanceof) !! 
        if (duplicateError instanceof Database.DuplicateError) {
            // Now that were type-safe, lets do our casting 
            Datacloud.DuplicateResult duplicateResult = ((Database.DuplicateError)duplicateError).getDuplicateResult();
            // Then debug our results 
            System.debug('Duplicate records have been detected by ' + 
                      duplicateResult.getDuplicateRule());
            System.debug(duplicateResult.getErrorMessage());
        } else {
            // Should catch all other errors 
            System.debug('Error thrown but not a dupe result');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation. I will definitely check it and will provide you with the updates. And yes you logic seems right.